# Cannot create SharePoint site column

Tags: xml, powershell, sharepoint

I've been trying to use PowerShell and Site Features to update existing or previously exist site columns (quite a few). Adding site columns using SharePoint Designer or C# code or `$web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml` without ID attribute are all working fine. However, because field GUIDs must be retained for my project, once I use the GUID previously deployed, SharePoint reports error.

This is how I get error using PowerShell: (ID is a unique value)

`<Field
       ID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
       Name="CustomField"
       DisplayName="Custom Field"
       Type="Boolean"
       Required="FALSE"
       Overwrite="TRUE"
       OverwriteInChildScopes="TRUE"
       Group="Custom Columns">
  </Field>`

`$web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($xml)`

`Exception calling "AddFieldAsXml" with "1" argument(s): ""
At line:1 char:1
+ $web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($xml)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException`

But if I remove ID property or use a new ID it will create column as expected.

The same happens when I activate Feature. The Log shows:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)), StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.FetchFieldsFromWeb()`

`Unable to locate the xml-definition for FieldName with FieldId '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`

I suspect it was corrupt field in Site Collection so I deleted a few columns but now I cannot add them back and update content types - please help!

Comment: Those "deleted" fields cannot be found using any of these: PowerShell, SPD, Visual Studio..

Comment: Are you adding it like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798370.aspx#Y209 see if `web.AvailableFields.Contains(MyFieldId)` is already in use.

Comment: @HAL9256 I tried already. using c# code it returns error when adding column with the same GUID of the "deleted" column. $web.AvailableFields.ContainsFieldWithStaticName("CustomField") return False

Answer (score 0):

I had a perhaps related issue where I was unable to add columns which I thought I had previously deleted.

It turned out that these deleted columns were first stored in the site recycle bin.

After emptying that bin, I still could not re add the deleted columns.

This was ultimately caused by the deleted columns still being present in the site collection recycle bin.

See : [SP recycle bins](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/09/sharepoint-recycle-bins-lets-get-it-clear.html)

Could your issue be related?

Comment: I tried to empty both web recycle bin and site collection recycle bin. It still returns same error even after I disabled recycle bins from web application settings.